# Mysql Sharding. Application Layer vs Mysql Layer

Tags: mysql, best-practices, sharding

I am going to create shards in mysql table and I am stuck at a dileman whether to go for application layer sharding or let MySQL handle it. 
I mean, wether I should be figuring  out which shard to go and query at application layer or pass on the query to the MySQL driver and let it decide.

I read about some pros and cons of both [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541421/mysql-sharding-approaches) but I am unable to come up with a conclusion.

My personal opinion is to go for the MySQL driver handling it. Open for discussion on this.

Please share your views/experiences.

Comment: *I am going to create shards in mysql table* Vertical or horizontal? And what's the main goal of this?

Comment: @Akina Vertical shards based in an id.

Comment: What's the goal? to shard for to shard makes no sense.

Comment: Actually want to divide the media content which id wise (which is going to be a lot) into diffrent shards for efficient search

Comment: ? Does you want to divide your data array on searcheable and non-searcheable parts? Nevertheless I think that it won't improve searching process.

Comment: @Akina Ohh Alright, I will think from that point too. But, say in general,  Application Layer vs Mysql Layer. What can be a better approach?

Comment: Any operation with dataarray which may be effectively performed on the SQL server must be performed on the SQL server I think. Especially when the SQL server is remote.

Comment: I don't know of a driver that provides sharding; please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

Sharding does *not* speed up searching.

Sharding is useful when you hit a write-scaling limit.  Most social media apps end up with some form of sharding to handle *many* thousands of *writes* per second.

MySQL has no sharding capability.  However, add-ons, such as Spider and various Proxies can help.

Or you can build it into the application layer.  In this case, each client must first figure out which database shard to talk to, then talk only to that one.  This assumes all the activity can be handled in a single shard.

Sure, the application layer may make use of database tables to keep track of what shards exist, and which item is in which shard.